# Better way to improve the for loop for my case in R?

Tags: r

Prob stat : 
data set holds two columns mstr_program_list, Loc_cat with 600000. Loc_cat column holds both missing and non missing cells. Other columns are not havings NA's. for each prog in mstr_program_list, need to find total number of loc-cat associated with that program, % of non missing rows and among non missing rows find count of categories its divided into.

Ex : for Unknown prog - total number of rows = 3, non missing rows in loc_cat is one  therefore % is (2/3)*100 and number of categories divided  into is two (Rests:full) (Rests:lim)

```
   > head(data)
        L.Name                   mstr_program_list            loc_cat
    1  Six J'SGroup                   Unknown              <NA>
    2  Bj's- Maine             Roasted Tomat               Rests: Full
    3  Bj's- Maine                     Unknown             Rests: Full
    4  Brad's Q Q                      Unknown             Rests: lim
```

expected output:

```
     mstr_prog   total_count    %good(non missing rows)   Number of loc_cat
     Unknown         3                      66.7                     2
```

the code below is taking a lot of time. In fact results are not showing. Can anyone help me to improve the code.  Prob with this code as per my view is the adding vectors.

Upon research I came to know to add values to vector not to use append and go with c()

```
v <- c(v, 'y') # adding elements into a vector
```

Code:

```
data          <- read.csv("MgData.csv",header=T, na.strings="", colClasses = classes,      nrows = 600338,comment.char="")                           ## import data.
data_NoNull   <- na.omit(data)
mpl_unique    <- unique(data$mstr_program_list)
mas_Prog_List <- as.character()
loc_Count     <- as.numeric()
per_Seg       <- as.numeric()
num_Seg       <- as.numeric()
for(i in 1:length(mpl_unique)) {
    l_t <- length(data$mstr_program_list[data$mstr_program_list == i])   # loc_cat specific to prog
    l_g <- length(data_NoNull$mstr_program_list[data_NoNull$mstr_program_list == i])    ## to know filled ones excluding empty
    s <- subset(data_NoNull, mstr_program_list==i, select =c(loc_cat))
    if((any(i == mas_Prog_List)) == FALSE) {
        no_Seg <- nrow(unique(s))
        mas_Prog_List <- c(mas_prog_list, i)                 # Adding values to vector
        loc_Count     <- c(loc_count, l_t)
        perct_Seg     <- ((l_g/l_t)*100)
        per_Seg       <- c(per_Seg, perct_seg)
        Num_Seg       <- c(Num_Seg, no_seg)
        }
       }
      }
 Seg_analysis <- data.frame(mas_Prog_List, loc_Count, per_Seg, num_Seg)
```

I am new to R. Correct me with changes in the code, naming convention/ terminology used.
Thanks

Comment: Can you add a small example dataset to your question? Even `head(data)` would be good. It looks like there may be numerous issues with the code but it's hard to tell without knowing what the variables are.

Comment: Does mstr_program_list have NA's? All unknowns in this variable should be grouped?

Comment: mstr_program_list not having any NA's. Unknown is a string in that column. Only loc_cat holds NA's

Comment: Updated the question. Made it more clear

Comment: I would try to rewrite using *apply.  I don't totally understand what you want to get (would be good to add expected results for the data you added) but I don't think your program is doing what you think. Do you really just want the last values?

Comment: Updated expected results. I need to find for a specific prog in master_program_list        find total number of times its repeated wrt loc_cat. % of non missing rows in loc_cat . Among non missing rows into how many they are subdivided in loc_cat. Here Unknown total numb- 3 . % of non missing 66.7%(i.e, two out of 3).  categorized into only one Rest_full

Comment: So you are counting the `loc_cat` variable.  Do you ignore the `L.Name` variable or do you want to count it or use it as a grouping variable?

Comment: Ignore L.Name. Counting loc_cat with respect to each mstr_prg_list